# how is combination of prefix and postfix operator are evaluated

Tags: c++

how the result of the code below is 2?

`int i=2,j;
 j=i++ + --i;
 cout<<j;`

It is evaluating --i first and then i++,but it should be other way round i.e.(postfix increment having higher precedence should be executed first), so the answer should be 4.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, no, it is *unspecified* which side of the `+` will be evaluated first. Due to this and because those operations act on the same variable, your program has undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. Don't ever write code like this.

Comment: What happened to don't answer obvious dupes?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Haha just testing whether you're paying attention ^_^